# Best three tier C# Implement "style"

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# three tier implement and I've found a lot of implementations in Internet. I don't know what difference and benefit from its .

[alt text http://photo.1280.com/images/n8b/61YRE697/myteacher.jpeg](http://photo.1280.com/images/n8b/61YRE697/myteacher.jpeg)
[alt text http://photo.1280.com/images/wnh/0JZCDRM5/another.jpeg](http://photo.1280.com/images/wnh/0JZCDRM5/another.jpeg)

Thanks a lot for reading this and I'm waiting for your answers. And I really want to know your implementation :)

Comment: You mean 3-tier architecture using layers?

Comment: 3-tier architecture is a concept. It is not programming language specific. There are many good books available that explain in great depth the various ways of structuring enterprise applications. That's where you should start looking.

Comment: This question should get the architecture tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3-tier architecture isn't language dependent. It's a way of structuring your applications.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)

> Three-tier architecture has the following three tiers:
>
> **Presentation tier**
>
> This is the topmost level of the application. The presentation tier displays information related to such services as browsing merchandise, purchasing, and shopping cart contents. It communicates with other tiers by outputting results to the browser/client tier and all other tiers in the network.
>
> **Application tier**
>
> (Business Logic/Logic Tier/Data Access Tier/Middle Tier) 
>   The logic tier is pulled out from the presentation tier and, as its own layer, it controls an application’s functionality by performing detailed processing.
>
> **Data tier**
>
> This tier consists of Database Servers. Here information is stored and retrieved. This tier keeps data neutral and independent from application servers or business logic. Giving data its own tier also improves scalability and performance.

[image]

Since your asking this question in relation to C# you could take a look at this article-> [Designing a .NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973829.aspx)

Another link from stackoverflow which has a bunch of good answers -> [3 Tier Architecture - In need of an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011698/3-tier-architecture-in-need-of-an-example)