# 3 tier architecture references

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, 3-tier

I am looking for references on 3-tier architecture with ASP.Net. Can you please provide some links?

Comment: have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011698/3-tier-architecture-in-need-of-an-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Csla framework is designed to build your business objects on top of, using n-tier architectures.  You objects can be used in any UI technology as they'll fully support databinding, and data access is 100% up to you so Sql Server is easy to use, whether its via straight ado.net, EF, Linq 2 Sql or NHibernate.

If you want something that excludes anything but Asp.Net, C# and Sql server though, well you're probably not going to find it.

http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet

Answer (score 0):

Sharp Architecture is a very good starting place. Not only is it a framework, but it will help you learn the fundamentals of n-tiered development, while making it easy and comprehendable to design your application.

http://www.sharparchitecture.net/

It uses Castle, NHibernate and asp.net mvc.

Comment: would you pls send the link only 3 tier architechure using asp.net and c# and sql server

Comment: The link is in my post. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I think he doesn't want the Castle, NHibernate, and MVC stuff.

Comment: like @Andy said below "If you want something that excludes anything but Asp.Net, C# and Sql server though, well you're probably not going to find it."