# ASP .NET MVC with ADO .NET causing issues?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm new to both ADO .NET and MVC, and I am trying to do something simple where I am editting a "DailyReport", which is basically representing a work-report.

Here's my relevant controller pattern:

```
    //
    // GET: /DailyReport/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id, int weeklyReportID, int day)
    {

        WeeklyReport weeklyReport = (
                                      from WeeklyReport wr in db.WeeklyReports 
                                      where wr.Id == weeklyReportID select wr)
                                      .FirstOrDefault();

        ViewBag.Week = weeklyReport.Week;
        ViewBag.Day = day;

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /DailyReport/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(DailyReport dailyReport, int weeklyReportID, int day)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.SaveChanges();

            if (dailyReport == null)
            {

                dailyReport = new DailyReport();
                dailyReport.StartTime = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
                dailyReport.EndTime = new TimeSpan(7 + 8, 0, 0);
                dailyReport.Day = day;

                db.DailyReports.AddObject(dailyReport);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            WeeklyReport weeklyReport = (
                                         from WeeklyReport wr in db.WeeklyReports 
                                         where wr.Id == weeklyReportID select wr)
                                         .FirstOrDefault();

            if (!weeklyReport.DailyReport.Any(dr => dr.Id == dailyReport.Id))
            {
                weeklyReport.DailyReport.Add(dailyReport);
            }

            dailyReport.WeeklyReport = weeklyReport;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Edit", 
                                    "WeeklyReport", 
                                     new { 
                                           id = weeklyReportID, 
                                           week = weeklyReport.Week, 
                                           year = weeklyReport.Year 
                                         });

        }

        return View(dailyReport);
    }
```

When I am editting the datetime value, it doesn't get saved. In the HttpPost section when I debug it, the object is indeed changed to reflect these changes, but calling db.SaveChanges() doesn't commit it to the database.

**Edit** "db" in this case is my ADO .NET context, declared in the following way:

```
    ActivesEntities db = new ActivesEntities();
```

ActivesEntities has this declaration:

```
    public partial class ActivesEntities : ObjectContext { ... }
```

Comment: BTW and non related to the question, having the Controller to call the db directly is never a good idea ... separate your code into layers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510396/business-layer-in-3-tier-architecture/7510526#7510526

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is indeed relevant. I updated the question.

Comment: I still need help with the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend you to not call the `db.SaveChanges` until you really need to save an Entity object in the middle of the series of Transactional Steps..

Because Entity Framework support saving all the EntityContext object in a single shot !

And I think you may try changing the code like this,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(DailyReport dailyReport, int weeklyReportID, int day)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        if (dailyReport == null)
        {
            dailyReport = new DailyReport();
            dailyReport.StartTime = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
            dailyReport.EndTime = new TimeSpan(7 + 8, 0, 0);
            dailyReport.Day = day;

            db.DailyReports.AddObject(dailyReport);
        }

        WeeklyReport weeklyReport = (from WeeklyReport wr in db.WeeklyReports where wr.Id == weeklyReportID select wr).SingleOrDefault();
        if (!weeklyReport.DailyReport.Any(dr => dr.Id == dailyReport.Id))
        {
            weeklyReport.DailyReport.Add(dailyReport);
        }

        dailyReport.WeeklyReport = weeklyReport;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "WeeklyReport", new { id = weeklyReportID, week = weeklyReport.Week, year = weeklyReport.Year });

    }
```

I think using if you are Updating the entity object then you need to call `SingleOrDefault` and not `FirstOrDefault`. I do it like this on Linq2Sql..

Answer (score 0):

you are using entity framework right? it's a bit different from ADO.NET (it uses it but those are not 100% same thing), we should add the tag EF to the question.

said so, why do you call `db.SaveChanges` twice? I would not call it at the top of your Edit method.

also, as I see in some EF examples, you can use `Add` and not `AddObject`.

check this one:

[How to: Add, Modify, and Delete Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386870.aspx)

last thing, your StartTime and EndTime properties of the object are of type `TimeSpan` and not datetime?

Comment: Davide: You have the priviliges to add the EF tag yourself, you know?

Comment: of course but need his answer first, looks like he uses EF but just wanted to hear from him ;-)

Comment: I don't think it's EF. I think it's ADO .NET. I changed from the default to have LiNQ.

Comment: Given that it's not EF, can you help me?

Comment: There is no dbcontext in raw ADO.NET, so I guess it must be EF!